# Android Volley SlowRequests troubles

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to configure volley to accept slow requests. For that I set the timeout as below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RequestQueue MyRequestQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    startQueue();
    post();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


private void startQueue(){
    // Instantiate the cache
    Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap
    // Set up the network to use HttpURLConnection as the HTTP client.
    Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
    // Instantiate the RequestQueue with the cache and network.
    this.MyRequestQueue  = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
    // Start the queue
    this.MyRequestQueue.start();

}

public void post() {


    Map<String, String> MyData= new HashMap<String,String>();
    MyData.put("param1","etc");
    MyData.put("param2", "etc");


    String urlpost ="example.com";

    StringRequest MyStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, urlpost,  new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("response", response);
        }

    },  new Response.ErrorListener() { //Create an error listener to handle errors appropriately.
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i("error", String.valueOf(error));

        }}) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

            return MyData;
        }

    };

    MyStringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            400000,//timeout 400000 ms
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    MyStringRequest.setPriority(Request.Priority.HIGH);

    MyRequestQueue.add(MyStringRequest);
}
```

}

Still I'm receiving "BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request" in 7 seconds after request and the volley gets half the content it should. When I execute the same request in a browser, everything works normally.

What could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Handle Volley timeouts you need to use a RetryPolicy. A retry policy is used in case a request cannot be completed due to network failure or some other cases.

Volley provides an easy way to implement your RetryPolicy for your requests. By default, Volley sets all socket and connection timeouts to 5 seconds for all requests.

The constructor takes the following three parameters:

initialTimeoutMs - Specifies the socket timeout in milliseconds for every retry attempt.
maxNumRetries - The number of times retry is attempted.
backoffMultiplier - A multiplier which is used to determine exponential time set to socket for every retry attempt.

and if you want to set on custom default time of volley response

1.you want to follow this code

```
 RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(request);
        request.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
            @Override
            public int getCurrentTimeout() {
                return 50000;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
                return 50000;
            }

            @Override
            public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {

            }
        });
```

I think this code is helpful of every volley user for getting response by slow network connection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your code worked. The volley has a longer time response, but it is still not working, even leaving 3 minutes, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: ok dear please check your api in postman how long time getting response in postman .

Comment: In a browser it takes about 7 seconds to get response.